# testing SSL server loads

Tags: ssl, testing, jmeter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

There has been a lot of talk about SSL creating excess CPU/memory load on websites. What I want to do is test this on my VPS/my brothers dedicated server. Will I be missing something important if I use apache JMeter and skipfish to create http/https server loads while monitoring/logging with htop? I plan on launching the load from an amazon ec2 interface so there will be as much bandwith as possible.

Answer (score 4):

> There has been a lot of talk about SSL creating excess CPU/memory load
>   on websites.

Really? Where? I have never once heard of moving to SSL causing CPU-releated problems.

Unless your webserver is already CPU-bound (highly unlikely), you won't even notice the additional CPU load that SSL causes.

You should be able to test HTTPS performance in the exact same way you test HTTP performance. You'll just need to make sure that your load testing tool(s) support HTTPS, and that they trust whatever CA signed your certificate.

Comment: I agree with you, but many people seem to disagree. Do you have a particular tool you recomend?

Comment: @Jeremy: Which people?  What resource are you basing this on?

Comment: One complicating factor in HTTPS testing is getting a realistic client behaviour in the area of SSL session caching -- but that's primarily an issue if you're testing for connection latency rather than "website performance" (but if you only care about that, you wouldn't test over HTTPS in the first place).